# Join numbers with whitespace in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, whitespace

Writing a simple loop for a Lisp program, I want my numbers to be printed with whitespace in between them,

```
(loop for i from 1 to 5
      do 
      (prin1  i))
```

prints:

```
12345
```

id like it to print:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

but i cant find any info on printing whitespace anywhere. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will somehow need to print the whitespace yourself.  Simple extension of your code:

```
(loop for i from 1 to 5
      do (princ i)
         (princ #\space))
```

(Note that I used `princ` instead of `prin1`.)

Answer (score 6):

All sufficiently-mature programming languages go through a stage of having another programming language embedded in strings, often to control printed output.  *Really* mature programming languages pass this stage: CL is not yet that mature, and still has `FORMAT` control strings.  And you can do all sorts of things with these.

A slight variant of your example is to get `FORMAT` to print a list:

```
> (format t "~&~{~A~^, ~}.~%" '(1 2 3 4 5))
1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
```

What this control string means is:

1. `~&` – be at the start of the line;
2. `~{` – start an iteration over a list;
3. `~A` – print each element as with `PRINC`;
4. `~^` – after printing the last element, stop here;
5. `,` – print a comma and a space for every other element;
6. `~}` – end of the loop over elements;
7. `.` – print a stop at the end of the list;
8. `~%` – print  a newline character.

This is a relatively simple example of using [`FORMAT` control strings](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm): it is possible to do some fairly hairy things.

---

(In fact, of course, CL being CL it's obviously possible to seamlessly add some more structured output-control language to the language, and I'm sure people have done that.  So CL has passed the stage in some sense: `FORMAT` control strings are just, for some people, a fossilized remmnant).

Comment: LOL Are you calling PHP and JavaScript more mature than CL?

Comment: @Sylwester no, less: the language-in-a-string thing is a phase languages go through when they get grown-up enough.

Comment: Which programming languages have this feature today?

Comment: I disagree with the correlation between out-of-the-box language-in-a-string and the language's maturity, especially because it largely depends on the language's purpose, but C# for one has string interpolation, e.g. `$"{expression}"`.  CL has always had the possibility for any kind of string magic through custom macro characters, so I guess it depends more on the maturity of the user.  For an equivalent, mature, modern and open-source example, see cl-interpol.  For a reason why it's not a much more requested feature, see the `~?` recursive format directive.

Comment: @Sylwester: Fortran has hairy format strings.  Any language with regexps as part of the language has a language-in-a-string.

Comment: @acelent: my remark was intended an an allusion to [Zawinski's law of software envelopment](http://catb.org/jargon/html/Z/Zawinskis-Law.html), not as a literal statement.  Obviously fewer people know about that than I expected.

Answer (score 4):

With a library, printing a string:

```
(ql:quickload "str")
(str:join " " (loop for i from 1 to 5 collect i))
;; "1 2 3 4 5"
```

https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str/

more:

- https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html
- and a primer on iteration (loop, iterate, for, series, mapcar): https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html

but I encourage the use of `format`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format function with format directives:

```
(loop for i from 1 to 5
      do
      (format t "~A " i))
```

your output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

The ~A directive is simply a place holder for a value, in this case the value stored in the variable i. This is similar to Pythons format function.

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER 67 > (loop with start = 1 and end = 5
                   for i from (1+ start) to end
                   initially (princ start)
                   do (princ #\space) (princ i))
1 2 3 4 5
NIL
```